# How to implement HECTOR SLAM in standalone GAZEBO or do i require ROS or RVIZ

Tags: ros, rviz

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am new to Gazebo.
Installed standalone version of Gazebo 1.7 i guess.
I did it for simulating **Autonomous Robot Navigation**, my final year project.

But by surfing net and looking for how to do path planning, i got some videos and chunks of help but were all related to ROS or RVIZ.

[Autonomous Driving Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDRl5Kmx2lk)

And whenever i go to ROS it says me

> *Users are highly discouraged from using the outdated documentation and
> tutorials for Gazebo on ros.org.
> Gazebo is now a stand alone project at
> gazebosim.org. See documentation
> there, thanks!*

And i return back.

I read that there are at the moment two most commonly used SLAM implementations in 2D are GMapping/OpenSLAM and Hector SLAM.
They were for ROS.

Kindly let me know and guide me how todo that stuff in GAZEBO STANDALONE or if its not possible, help me with this using ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4386/how-to-implement-hector-slam-in-standalone-gazebo-or-do-i-require-ros-or-rviz/) by [SalmaanAhmed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/394/salmaanahmed/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ROS used to pull in a specific version of Gazebo. ROS has since stopped this practice, and now uses the normal standalone version of Gazebo. All this means is that ROS uses the system install of Gazebo, and documentation about Gazebo on ros.org is outdated.

Gazebo is still fully compatible with ROS, see [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#ROS_Integration).

If you want robot control, you'll need to use software like Player or ROS.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2